# WTF WPF TabControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, xamlparseexception

I believe this to be a bug in WPF (v4.0 if it matters), but it is late, and maybe I'm missing something.

I am binding to a fake example for illustrative purposes:

```
    <x:Array x:Key="SampleItems" Type="sys:String">
        <sys:String>Foo</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Bar</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Baz</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
```

This works and displays three tabs with the same header and content:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource SampleItems}">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding}" />
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}" />
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
```

However, this throws an exception with the message "Error 10 Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.":

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource SampleItems}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!-- Anything here causes this problem. -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

It is important to note that this is reproducible with any text in either TextBlock.  In fact, I can replace the header TextBlock with any XAML and get this message.  I'm at a loss to explain this.  Any ideas, or is this just a bug?

The problem appears in the VS designer, but here is a portion of the relevant stack trace at runtime as well:

```
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ChangeLogicalParent(DependencyObject newParent)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.AddLogicalChild(Object child)
   at System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedContentControl.OnHeaderChanged(Object oldHeader, Object newHeader)
   at System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedContentControl.OnHeaderChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyStyleOrTemplateValue(FrameworkObject fo, DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateContainerDependents(DependencyObject container, FrugalStructList`1& exclusionContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1& oldContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1& newContainerDependents)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.DoStyleInvalidations(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateStyleCache(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle, Style& styleCache)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.ApplyItemContainerStyle(DependencyObject container, Object item)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.MS.Internal.Controls.IGeneratorHost.PrepareItemContainer(DependencyObject container, Object item)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator.PrepareItemContainer(DependencyObject container)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.GenerateChildren()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically what you are doing is assigning the very same instance of a TextBlock to each TabItem.  On the first iteration, the TextBlock is added to the first TabItem. On the second iteration, the *very same* TextBlock is added to the visual tree. The error message you see is trying to tell you that the TextBlock can't have two parents (there is a joke there somewhere).

You *can* set a template for these, however. A template instructs the TabItem to create a new set of whatever visual you want per item created.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource SampleItems}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Of course.  Even though the net XAML was approximately the same, where in the working case a TextBlock was being inserted for each bound string, the key difference is that a new TextBlock was being generated for each string.  In the failing case, I was telling it to use the same one over and over.  Shame on me.