# WPF's tab items: Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, tabcontrol

I have a CloseableTabControl with CloseableTabItems I'm trying to add dynamically:

```
public class CloseableTabControl : TabControl
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new CloseableTabItem();
    }
}  


public class CloseableTabItem : TabItem
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent CloseTabEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("CloseTab", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(CloseableTabItem));

    public event RoutedEventHandler CloseTab
    {
        add { AddHandler(CloseTabEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(CloseTabEvent, value); }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var closeButton = Template.FindName("closeButton", this) as Button;
        if (closeButton != null)
        closeButton.Click += CloseButtonClick;
    }

    void CloseButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(CloseTabEvent, this));
    }
}
```

and the XAML is as follows:

```
    <local:CloseableTabControl Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex}" ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}">
    <local:CloseableTabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TestEditor:TestEditorViewModel}">
             <TestEditor:TestEditorView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TestParameterEditor:TestParameterEditorViewModel}">
             <TestParameterEditor:TestParameterEditorView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:CloseableTabControl.Resources>
    <local:CloseableTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="local:CloseableTabItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="Border" Background="{DynamicResource Brush2}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Brush5}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="6,6,0,0" >
                            <DockPanel>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                     ContentSource="Header"
                                     Margin="12,2,12,2"/>
                                <Button Name="closeButton" 
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                     Margin="3,0,3,0" 
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                     Width="16" 
                                     Height="16" 
                                     DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                                     Style="{DynamicResource CloseableTabItemButtonStyle}" 
                                     ToolTip="Close Tab">
                                     <Path Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="#FF333333" Fill="#FF969696" Data="F1 M 2.28484e-007,1.33331L 1.33333,0L 4.00001,2.66669L 6.66667,6.10352e-005L 8,1.33331L 5.33334,4L 8,6.66669L 6.66667,8L 4,5.33331L 1.33333,8L 1.086e-007,6.66669L 2.66667,4L 2.28484e-007,1.33331 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                </Button>
                            </DockPanel>
                         </Border>
                      </Grid>
                      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                          <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                              <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource lightBrush}" />
                          </Trigger>
                          <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                              <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Brush1}" />
                          </Trigger>
                      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Header">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="{Binding Caption}">
                         <Image Height="18" Source="{Binding ImageName}"/>
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="2,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Style>
      </local:CloseableTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
  </local:CloseableTabControl>
```

Everything is fine when I'm adding only one tab in this window's viewmodel's constructor:

```
TabItems.Add(TestEditorViewModel);
```

but when I'm adding more than one I'm getting the mentioned exception.
I've tried to follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936269/how-can-i-use-a-custom-tabitem-control-when-databinding-a-tabcontrol-in-wpf) and separate the XAML to `ItemTemplate` and `ContentTemplate` but this caused a `StackOverFlowException` (that is caused by the `ContentPresenter` part of the template, I have no idea why).
Any ideas how should I approach this?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your `Setter` for the `Header` property. When the first `TabItem` has the `Style` applied, a new `StackPanel` will be created. When the second `TabItem` is created and has the `Style` applied the **same** `StackPanel` will be assigned to its `Header` property. In WPF a visual can only have 1 parent, so you receive the stated exception above. Instead you should define a `HeaderTemplate` which contains the `StackPanel` so that each time the `Style` is applied for a `TabItem` a **new** `StackPanel` is generated when WPF inflates the `HeaderTemplate`.

Please see this related post:

[WTF WPF TabControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748992/wtf-wpf-tabcontrol)

Cheers!

Comment: I think we replied at about the same time :)

Comment: I've always thought of this error as being similar to giving multiple people the same cookie to eat. It just doesn't work. You need to instead give them each the cookie recipe (Template) for them to go make their own cookies :)

Comment: I realized that the problem is somewhere there and indeed removed the header definition to a template, but without fully understanding it. If you can explain why the `Style` applies the **same** `StackPanel` (why can't the same `Style` be applied to different elements) it would be very kind of you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was

```
<Setter Property="Header">
    <Setter.Value>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="{Binding Caption}">
            <Image Height="18" Source="{Binding ImageName}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="2,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

inside the style. I'm not sure what causes it exactly, I think it's the content being set twice for some reason, but the solution is to use

```
 <local:CloseableTabControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="{Binding Caption}">
              <Image Height="18" Source="{Binding ImageName}"/>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="2,0,0,0"/>
         </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
 </local:CloseableTabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Any explanations as to what exactly is the problem will be most welcome.